# How to optimize this "where IN" and "where NOT IN" query?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

The following query/queries get the cities the user has visited, get the places where the user has visited; and returns the places in those cities where the user hasn't been.

```
// I get the city_id and object_id. Each vote has the place_id and its city_id.
  SELECT DISTINCT city_id as city_id, object_id as object_id
    FROM vote
   WHERE object_model = 'Place'
     AND user_id = 20
ORDER BY created_at desc

// I build an array with city_ids and another with object_ids
$city_ids = array(...);
$place_ids = array(...);
```

I get the places where the user hasn't been in the cities he has been - 1 second

```
  SELECT id, title
    FROM place
   WHERE city_id IN ($city_ids)
     AND id NOT IN ($place_ids)
ORDER BY points desc
   LIMIT 0,20
```

EXPLAIN SQL

```
select_type table   type    possible_keys           key             key_len   ref    ows     Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SIMPLE      p       range   PRIMARY,city_id_index    city_id_index    9         NULL  33583    Using where; Using filesort
```

Another attempt to optimize is to do it one query using LEFT JOIN / IS NULL and a subquery, but it takes much longer (30+ seconds)

```
   SELECT id, title 
     FROM place AS p
LEFT JOIN vote v ON v.object_id = p.id
                AND v.object_model = 'Place'
                AND v.user_id = 20
    WHERE p.city_id IN (SELECT city_id 
                          FROM vote 
                         WHERE user_id = 20 
                           AND city_id != 0)
      AND v.id is null
 ORDER BY p.points desc
    LIMIT 0, 20
```

How would you do the query/queries thinking that we can have an array of 500 cities and 1000 places for each user? Which is the best alternative to where in and where NOT IN when there are many ids?

Answer (score 1):

I am no MySQL expert, but I the query doesn't look too complex. Instead of focusing on the query, I would look at the indexes. Maybe the following indexes will help:

```
CREATE INDEX vote_index1 ON vote (user_id, city_id)
CREATE INDEX vote_index2 ON vote (object_id, object_model, user_id)
```

Comment: Yea, this seems to be an missing index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query for 2 attributes you need to join 2 tables and not only 1 table. Also I want to know what is object_id?

```
SELECT id, title 
 FROM place AS p
LEFT JOIN vote v ON v.object_id = p.id
            AND v.object_model = 'Place'
            AND v.user_id = 20
LEFT JOIN place AS P1 on V.city_id = P1.city_id
WHERE v.id is null
ORDER BY p.points desc
 LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: if object_model='Place' then object_id = place_id

Comment: fesj: I've corrected my answer. You need to left join 2 tables if you want to query to attributes or 2 variables. Did you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `IN` operator, just try to solve with joining all the tables necesary. The `IN` can be accomplished with normal join I believe, and the `NOT IN` you accomplish by e.g.:

```
select *
from a left join b using (field)
where b.field is NULL
```

this way you get all records from table a where there is no corresponding record in table b.

Comment: Tomas: That'S to vague anwser.

Comment: How is my answer vague? We just put advices, we are not supposed to get acquainted with complex code and tables, if we don't know the structure etc. I think the one who asks must put his own effort to try! Or, to simplify his question enough to show the core of the problem.

Comment: Tomas: You are right, it's just my bad day and I tried to be nice.

Comment: Jitamaro: OK, pleased to meet you. :)

Comment: In fact I overlooked the USING (field) but is this that important? An example would be nice!

Comment: Yes Jitamaro, you must specify the field by which to join the tables, and this is the easiest way. You can also use the `on` clause, or `natural join`.

Answer (score 0):

When using mysql, you have to remember it is extremely dumb when handling IN() subqueries (or anything else really). So you should rewrite your second attempt as :

```
SELECT id, title 
FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT city_id FROM vote WHERE user_id = 20) v
JOIN places p USING (city_id)
LEFT JOIN vote v2 ON (v2.object_id = p.id AND v2.user_id = 20)
WHERE v2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY p.points desc
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Note that "city_id != 0" is useless, since there is a foreign key from votes to cities, so vote.city_id cannot be 0. It could be NULL though.

Also, the database design is probably wrong : cities should have their own table, the "table name + id" columns are a bad idea, etc.

Comment: why do you consider that *"table name + id" columns are a bad idea*?

Comment: because it makes the R in RDBMS irrelevant ;)

Comment: personally I see FK's much faster at columns having _id in the end - I think it's a matter of tastes - but I always encourage this naming covention

Comment: OK, misunderstanding. Naming your FKs "city_id" is good, I like to do it this way. Here we have a "vote" table with an "object_model" column which tells which table it refers to, and an "object_id" which gives the PK of the line which is referred to. So it's a sort of a compound multi-table foreign key (table+id) which doesn't really work.